# iPhone: How many digits should be after a dot of a float

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, stringwithformat

I´m trying to set the number of digits of a float with a segmented control.

So I've created an segmented control with "0", "1", "2" and "3".
I want to set the digits after the comma with a variable (`self._segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex`).

I know that I can decide how many digits after a comma should be like this:

```
sliderValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f",slider.value];
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: And your Xcode-related question is: ???

Comment: how can i set the number of digts with the output of self._segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex

Comment: the problem is that **that one is *not Xcode-related***.

Comment: Read the [fprintf spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html), particularly the section beginning "An optional minimum field width..."

Comment: ah ok, sorry i used it because i work with it

Comment: @H2CO3 -- Don't have a cow.  Half the Objective-C threads here are mis-tagged with "xcode".

Comment: @Hot Licks and that's inacceptable IMHO.

Comment: @MaxBurkhardt please read its tag wiki - it's clearly stated in there that you should not use this tag for general iOS programming questions. See, it's very frustrating for me since I develop for iOS without Xcode.

Comment: @H2CO3 -- But it should only be necessary to say "Please don't use the 'xcode' tag unless your question has to do with the Xcode development environment."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can even do it in one step:

```
sliderValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*f", numberOfDigits, slider.value];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in two steps.

```
NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%.%df", numberOfDigits);
sliderValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, slider.value];
```

Comment: Oh. My. God. You beated it to me with 8 seconds! And we even used the same variable name for the format string!

Comment: Downvoter: **reason???** Why somebody is coming here and randomly downvoting valid answers! Go screw yourself, anonymous killer! ***This answer is good!!!***

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%.%df", numberOfDecimalPlaces];
sliderValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, slider.value];
```

This should do the trick. Beware of format string attacks.

Comment: Wow, this time we almost got the exact same solution. :-)

Comment: Probably someone likes the one liner solution?

Comment: +1 Agree it's not a wrong answer - there are people like that now and then, though.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether this works or not. I only tested this with C++, but since the documentation for [String Format](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) points to [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html), I believe it should also work for Objective-C.

```
sliderValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.*f", places, slider.value];
```